# Python - Sorting a list by object attribute, in an order provided by a second list...can this be improved?

Tags: python, sorting

I have a list of immutable objects that I need to sort using an attribute as the key.

The objects need to be in a prespecified order, not simple ascending/descending.

I've written some code that does do this, but I don't have a lot of confidence that it would perform well with large lists (where "large" is entirely arbitrary). Today's use case is only small lists (12 items or less) but I've been alive long enough to expect a large one to get thrown at it eventually.

Is there a different approach, library or shortcut that I might be able to take advantage of to make this a more efficient operation?

```
# setup
class Demo(object):
    def __init__(self, pk):
        self.pk = pk

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'<Demo: {self.pk}>'

# instantiating objects for the sake of demonstration; actual input I'm given is random!
objects = [Demo(x) for x in range(10)]
# output object should be sorted by pk attribute, with values in this order
ordinality = [9, 0, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 6, 2]

# operation in question
result = (next(obj for obj in objects if obj.pk == ordinal) for ordinal in ordinality)

print(tuple(result))
>>> (<Demo: 9>, <Demo: 0>, <Demo: 8>, <Demo: 4>, <Demo: 5>, <Demo: 1>, <Demo: 3>, <Demo: 7>, <Demo: 6>, <Demo: 2>)
```

Comment: If your code is workable then your question should probably be valid for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your operation is _O(n**2)_ (poor). Using `[Demo(x) for x in ordinality]` directly would be _O(n)_.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to "sort", using an attribute as the key? Your code does not match your description at all.

Comment: @blhsing In the line commented with "operation in question".

Comment: @HeapOverflow Ah I get it now. Thanks.

Comment: @Ivan You'd better shuffle the objects to make the problem clearer and avoid answers like "why don't you just build them in the right order".

Comment: Btw, why do you want this weird random(?) order anyway? What are you really trying to solve? [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @HeapOverflow Closest analogue would be playlist management, where I am given a bucket of unordered objects and an integer list of their intended order for presentation to a particular user. This struck me as a basic intro-to-CS sorting problem and I did not want to overcomplicate it any more than that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming "pk" stands for "primary key" (unique), then instead of using a list of such objects (with *O(n)* membership) you can just use a dict (with *O(1)* membership)

```
objects = [Demo(x) for x in range(10)]  # O(n) space
result = [next(obj for obj in objects if obj.pk == ordinal] for ordinal in ordinality)  # O(n^2) time

objects = {x: Demo(x) for x in range(10)}  # O(n) space
result = [objects[pk] for pk in ordinal]  # O(n) time
```

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think to use dicts for this purpose; that makes a lot of sense. I knew there was something simple I was overlooking. Will try it out, thanks

Comment: Sweet! I didn't mention it since I didn't want a potentially Django-specific solution (it is not applicable across all of my use-cases), but where the list of objects in question *is* a Django queryset, it can be directly converted to that dictionary lookup format via the queryset `in_bulk` method. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Build a lookup-table first, then use that. Turns your O(n<sup>2</sup>) into O(n).

```
lookup = {obj.pk: obj for obj in objects}
result = [lookup[ordinal] for ordinal in ordinality)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use ordinality to create the objects. As ordinality is the order you want to begin with.

```
ordinality = [9, 0, 8, 4, 5, 1, 3, 7, 6, 2]

objects = list(map(Demo, ordinality))
#or
objects = [Demo(pk) for pk in ordinality]
```